# NSFetchedResultsController not calling delegate methods on changes using NSPredicate with subquery

Tags: ios, core-data

I have an `NSFetchedResultsController` that is created as follows:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Friendship")
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [
    NSSortDescriptor(key: "friendToCurrentUser.displayName", ascending: true)
]

fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(friendToCurrentUser.trackingSessions, $x, $x.dataIsStale == false AND $x.endDate == nil).@count != 0")

let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: CoreDataManager.instance.mainManagedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
var error: NSError?
if !fetchedResultsController.performFetch(&error) {
     println(error)
}
```

When the initial fetch completes the `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:` is called, but when an object should be added/removed due to the subquery this method is not called.

If this is as simple as delegate methods aren't called when the predicate contains a subquery then that's fine, but I've not managed to find that in any documentation. If this is true, is there an easy method to mimic/force these change delegate methods?

Comment: Why would a subquery in a predicate add/remove objects? The delegate methods should only be called after the FRC fetched its objects based on the predicate, not after each subquery iteration.

Comment: Maybe I didn't word my question very well. I am expecting that if I set the `dataIsStale` property to `true` after the initial fetch then the object should be removed from the results, which would then trigger a call to `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:` with a change type of `DELETE`

Comment: Can you add related code or how you were able to solve this? I have noticed similar issues with NSFetchedResultsController not calling the delegate but reloading the FRC will return the new results.